# Build WinForms app with TeeChart .NET in GitHub action CI/CD pipeline (TeeChart registration issue)

Tags: github, cicd, licensing, teechart

I am writing a **YAML** script to execute as a **GitHub action** on push & pull_request... Standard stuff.

Everything else works perfectly. But I cannot build my UI assembly that contains **TeeChart .NET**. When I try it throws a **licencing error**. It needs certain registry entries.

On my development PC I have to run TeeRegV3.exe, a GUI app, and enter in licence number and password, then it creates the registry entries that allow my project to build (development licence).

As an aside, the separate run-time licence is embedded in the shipped EXE.

Building on a GitHub "runner" (VM) is problematic. I can't (easily) run the UI app and enter the required info. I don't want to use a self-hosted runner - setup and maintenance will be an initial and ongoing pain. I really want a command line way of getting these registry entries created. They are probably machine specific so not much point in trying to copy them from my development machine.

I can't find any info on their forums.

I can't find any similar question on SO, or the wider internet.

I can't contact Steema support as that benefit expired about 10 years ago (licence for use is perpetual).

Surely I'm not the only person who needs TeeChart to work in an **automated CI/CD pipeline**.

Any ideas guys 'n gals?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit** - error message as requested -

Resources\licenses.licx(1): error LC0004: Exception occurred creating type 'Steema.TeeChart.TChart, TeeChart, Version=3.5.3498.27368, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c8126276c77bdb7' System.ComponentModel.LicenseException: An instance of type 'Steema.TeeChart.Chart' was being created, and a valid license could not be granted for the type 'Steema.TeeChart.Chart'. Please, contact the manufacturer of the component for more information.

As I said, it'll throw that if it doesn't find the registry entries I describe above, created by the TeeRegV3.exe GUI app...

As for posting the workflow as requested, ok sure, but it's not relevant hence not included in my original question... As I said, you just gotta build a project with TeeChart in it, on any machine, without having run the TeeRegTV3.exe GUI app / utility. The licencing error is not related to the GitHub action / workflow / runner environ per say, it's just about how to perform this registration action in an automated way, without needing a human to interact with this damn reg utility.

```
name: CI workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - develop
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - develop
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup MSBuild
        uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2

      - name: Setup NuGet
        uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.0.5

      - name: Restore NuGet packages
        run: nuget restore "<Solution name>.sln"

      - name: Build solution
        run: msbuild "<App name>\<App name>.wixproj" /p:Configuration="Release" 
p:Platform="x64" /p:TargetFrameworkVersion="v4.7.2" /p:RestorePackages=true
```

And final request - min steps to reproduce - add TeeChart to a project, don't licence it, and hit compile.

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and actual errors in your question

Comment: Post your current workflow please

Comment: Thanks for having a look ppl - edited question, additions as requested...